# How to get which() to return similar indices from two dataframes?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes (ma.sig, pricebreak) that look like this:

```
Date  A   B  C
01/1  1   0  1
02/1  1   0  1

Date  D   E  G
01/1  1   0  1
02/1  0   1  0
```

For starters, I just want to retrieve the column indices for all non-zero values in the first row. I tried doing this via the following methods:

```
sig <- which(!ma.sig[1,]==0&!pricebreak[1,]==0)
```

and

```
sig <- which(!ma.sig[1,]==0)&which(!pricebreak[1,]==0)
```

I would like it to return something like: 1, 3 (based in the above sample dataframe). However, I get this string of logical sequences:

[1] TRUE FALSE TRUE

How do I get it to return the columns indices? I do not want to use merge to merge my dataframes because of the nature of the data.

EDIT: Just for background information, the above data frames are 'signals' that are  on when the values are non-zero. I'm trying to use sig to collect indices that I can use for my main dataframe so that I can only calculate and print outputs when the signals are on.

Comment: What if the indices of non-zero values in the first row were to differ across the two data frames?

Comment: @RichScriven Then I would like it to not return anything.Sorry if my post was unclear, I tend to get a little scatterbrained when posting.

Comment: what is the expected output for the second row in your example?

Comment: @joel.wilson Right now I'm trying to look at the first row only, the second row will looked at in a different part of the program I'm trying to code. For the second part, I'd like to break down the output into x,y where x will return the row and y will return the column indices. If it makes sense, my dataframes above are just 'signals' and I'm trying to have R do calculations for specific variables  when these signals are 'on' (or in this case, not zero).

Comment: > which(!ma.sig[1,]==0&!pricebreak[1,]==0)
[1] 1 3
> !ma.sig[1,]==0&!pricebreak[1,]==0
  c.1..1. c.0..0. c.1..1..1
1    TRUE   FALSE      TRUE
This I get. If which yields the above output, try putting it in another "which(...)"

Comment: @SerhatCevikel I've tried sig <- which(!ma.sig[1,]==0)&which(!pricebreak[1,]==0) which still yields TRUE FALSE TRUE. Sorry, I should've added that in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@serhatCevikel already given the answer:
I am just trying to explain it more for your convenience.

```
 ma.sig =
 Date  A   B  C
 01/1  1   0  1
 02/1  1   0  1
 pricebrake = 
 Date  D   E  G
 01/1  1   0  1
 02/1  0   1  0
```

Now as per your method:

```
sig <- which(!ma.sig[1,]==0)&which(!pricebreak[1,]==0)
print(sig)
```

gives:
    TRUE TRUE TRUE
Now try:

```
which(sig)
```

it will return index of TRUE value:

```
  1 2 3
```

Please let me know if you get this. I have checked it twice in my terminal. Hope you will get this too.

Comment: Ah, I'm feeling really silly now. Thank you so much!